# Where can we find the username/password validation code for Joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

We're writing an API that allows users to sign up for a Joomla account through an external portal.  We want to do the password and username checking on the portal before submitting it through the API.  I've dug through the Joomla code and can't seem to find where those two fields get validated.  Does someone know where to look?  Joomla code makes finding a needle in a haystack look easy...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the `bind()` function in `libraries/joomla/user/user.php` as well as the helper functions that get called in `libraries/joomla/user/helper.php`. These classes are called from the `com_user` component.

If you have access to both the Joomla codebase and the external portal, it may be easier to create an authentication plugin that checks against the portal instead of using Joomla logins: http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3ACreating%5Fan%5FAuthentication%5FPlugin%5Ffor%5FJoomla%5F1.5

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like if the password is not null and is less than 100 characters, it is considered good.  Username is 150 characters.